# How to repair Error: Cannot find symbol in a Java class?

Tags: java, class, error-handling

I made this program and it looks fine, works fine in Intellij software. But whenever I submit in an online submission portal called "codepost.io" it shows me errors like:

```
No Result received.
[codePost Test] Question 1 Test:20: error: cannot find symbol

  if (!Modifier.isPrivate(Point.class.getDeclaredField("x").getModifiers()))
                          ^
symbol:   class Point
location: class Test
[codePost Test] Question 1 Test:24: error: cannot find symbol
  if (!Modifier.isPrivate(Point.class.getDeclaredField("y").getModifiers()))
                          ^
symbol:   class Point
location: class Test


[codePost Test] Question 1 Test:36: error: cannot find symbol
Point p0 = new Point(x, y);
  ^
symbol:   class Point
location: class Test
```

And my code was this:

```
public class A7 {
interface Relatable{
     public int isLargerThan(Relatable other);
}
static class Point implements Relatable{
    private int x;
    private int y;

    public Point(int x,int y){
        this.x=x;
        this.y=y;
    }
    public int getX(){
        return x;
    }

    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }
    public int getY(){
        return y;
    }

    public void setY(int y) {
        this.y = y;
    }
    public double getMagnitude(){
        double mag= Math.sqrt(Math.pow(getX(),2)+ Math.pow(getY(),2));
        return mag;
    }
    public int isLargerThan(Relatable other) {
        Point p = (Point)other;
        if (this.getMagnitude() < p.getMagnitude())
            return -1;
        else if (this.getMagnitude() > p.getMagnitude())
            return 1;
        else
            return 0;
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args){
    Relatable p1= new Point(1,2);
    Relatable p2= new Point(2,3);
    //Point p0= new Point(6,7);
    System.out.println(p1.isLargerThan(p2));
  }
}
```

I do not know why I am getting this error. Because it works fine in intellij software.

Comment: It looks like the site is trying to perform some kind of analysis on your code that it is unable to do. Did the instructions say to write a static nested class?

Comment: No. The question suggested to write only nested class, not static. But I have to use static otherwise I can't make object in main method

Comment: Actually I was able to create a test and submit your code both as an instructor as an student, so I don't know exactly how to reproduce the issue. :-(